# How to add meta info in using dask in this case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am trying to use dask to solve a pandas df memory issue, the api seems very simple as below:

```py
   
import dask.dataframe as dd
    
df = dd.read_csv(input_file, encoding='utf8', dtype=str, error_bad_lines=False, sep='\t', keep_default_na=False)

# ...
    
date_column = [get_today()] * row_count
headers = list(df)
if 'entry_date' not in headers:
    df["entry_date"] = date_column
```

However, this gives an error message:

```
    File "/builder/csv_data_preprocessor.py", line 65, in process
        df["entry_date"] = date_column
      File ".venv/kg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 4113, in __setitem__
        df = self.assign(**{key: value})
      File ".venv/kg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 4425, in assign
        df2 = self._meta_nonempty.assign(**_extract_meta(kwargs, nonempty=True))
      File ".venv/kg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 5752, in _extract_meta
        res[k] = _extract_meta(x[k], nonempty)
      File ".venv/kg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 5756, in _extract_meta
        "Cannot infer dataframe metadata with a `dask.delayed` argument"
    ValueError: Cannot infer dataframe metadata with a `dask.delayed` argument
```

How can I add metadata info. here to fix the error? The error message comes from:

```
df["entry_date"] = date_column
```

Comment: Do you mind to add a full [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using this:

```py
date_column = [get_today()] * row_count
```

is that it creates a large list in memory, possibly exceeding it. Dask also might not know how to allocate it across partitions. So the following should work (assuming that `get_today()` return a datetime object or a string):

```py
if 'entry_date' not in df.columns:
   df["entry_date"] = get_today()
```